# Probe emacs version from within a .emacs file?

Tags: version-support

I want to have a single `.emacs` file, under version control. Unfortunately, different systems have different versions of Emacs running. How do I detect the Emacs version from within Elisp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test variables `emacs-major-version` and `emacs-minor-version`, which return numbers.

You can also use functions (predicates) `version<`, `version<=`, and `version=` to test. Or functions `version-list-<`, `version-list-<=`, `version-list=`, and `version-list-not-zero`, together with function `version-to-list`.

Function `emacs-version` (or just `version`) returns a string completely describing the version.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I wanted. I did an apropos but didn't find those.